# Rotating a polygon is not working in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to rotate a polygon in windows forms using C# and below is code written .
Please tell me what wrong in the code, there is no output on windows form.
Before and after rotation polygons not visible.

```
public void RotatePolygon(PaintEventArgs e)
{ 
     pp[0] = new Point(624, 414);
            pp[1] = new Point(614, 416);
            pp[2] = new Point(626, 404);

            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(myPen2, pp);

            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix myMatrix1 = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix();
            myMatrix.Rotate(45, MatrixOrder.Append);
            myMatrix.TransformPoints(pp);


            e.Graphics.Transform = myMatrix1;
            e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(myPen, pp);   
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @Philip - given link is about WPF control rotation not in winforms.

Comment: @user1291401 Where do you call that method from?

Comment: Ah apologies, didn't see. I would presume this isn't actually being called if absolutely nothing is coming through. Try debugging to see what happens.

Comment: Forms Paint event this method is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code does not compile if left unmodified. There are two matrices used - one declared in your method (`myMatrix1`) attached to the graphics object and one declared outside your method (`myMatrix` without the `1`) used to explicitly transform the point array.

I tried the code with the required changes and it works flawless - I used `myMatrix1` for both transformations and the effective rotation angle was, as expected, twice the one specified. So I guess you are using two transformation that cancel if the transformed points end where they began.

Comment: thanx.. started working.. but how do i rotate from center of polygon ??

Comment: Translate by -center, rotate, and finally translate by +center.

Answer (score 1):

There could be this problems:

[1] your pens have no color/thickness (where do you define them?)

[2] your polygone is to big, so you only see the inside of it but not the border. --> Test Graphics.FillPolygon-Methode so you will see if [2] is right

Comment: Polygon is not very big.. it is small only.

Comment: Edited my answer: Test FillPolygon-method please.

Comment: XO find the error you generate a new matrix named myMatrix1 but rotate and transform a matrix named myMartix (without "1") ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're both transforming the points and changing the transform matrix for the Graphics object - you need to do one or the other.

You also need to think about the fact that the rotate is going to be happing about (0,0) rather than about some part of the object - you may well need a translate in there too.

Bear in mind that TransformPoints just manipulates some numbers in an array - which you can easily inspect with the debugger - this will be a more effective technique than displaying an invisible object and wondering where it went.

Starting with a much smaller rotation angle (10 deg, perhaps?) may also help with the problem of losing the object - it will be easier to work out what's happening if you haven't moved so far.